# How to remove a fire from the screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, compiz, knoppix

I've booted *Knoppix* with *Compiz* window manager on my MacBook and I've accidentally added a fire effect on the screen by holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking on the screen. Now I see a fire burning effect on my screen. Changing desktop doesn't help.

[image: Compiz's fire effect on the screen, Knoppix Linux]

How to destroy/remove that fire effect? What would be the keyboard shortcut to do that?

Answer (score 3):

The configuration for the Compiz effects can be found in *Preferences*, *CompizConfig Settings Manager*.

The effect is called *Firepaint* and the default shortcut to clear the effects from the screen is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. Super key in this case is the *Command* key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>).